# design email body

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

here it goes, i have this code

```
@MailSend(sample1;sample2:sample3; "";"sample, #"+number;
"Good Day! " +@NewLine+ "
Please click the link to see details of the sample for your Reference.. " +@NewLine+ " 
sample Details: ----->"+Category_1++@NewLine+"

Material 1----> "+Mat_1+@NewLine+"
Material 2----> "+Mat1_1+@NewLine+"
Material 3----> "+Mat2_1+@NewLine+"
Material 4----> "+Mat3_1+@NewLine+"
Material 5----> "+Mat4_1+@NewLine+"
Material 6----> "+Mat5_1+@NewLine+"
Material 7----> "+Mat6_1+@NewLine+"

Thanks "+@NewLine+" ";"";[IncludeDoclink])|
@Command([FileSave])|
@Command([CloseWindow]))
```

i wondering if i in this format how can i put table? like table view in php or table form.

Comment: same question (response in fact) see : http://dominoextnd.blogspot.co.il/2009/02/sending-email-from-xpage-should-it-be.html

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately in this format you can only add an ASCII grid, meaning you can add pipe and dash characters to present what appears to be a grid, and use a fixed width font with spaces to line up each column of data.  Though, you can't set the font with this method either, sadly.

You can build the entire email using LotusScript, though, using the rich text classes, including constructing the table programmatically.

Comment: Yes can i ask another question? there is a way to use strong character in lotus notes in my question for example, bold the material? when i receive it in my email ?

Comment: Unfortunately the same answer above applies to this question.  You could do that with the LotusScript Rich Text classes but not in your formula.

Answer (score 3):

In @MailSend, Your body content parameter is a text. So you can not insert any objects using @MailSend function.

If you want to insert any objects into the body content, You have two different ways.

One is Lotus script. You can use the NotesrichTextItem class for manipulating the body field.

Another way is @Formula, But it is not the straight way, You can use @Command(EditInsertTable) and @DialogBox("Memo")

Answer (score 2):

No, you would have to write LotusScript or Java code to do that.  The Notes forumula language can only deal with simple text messages.